# Generate unique username from first and last name?

Tags: mysql

I've got a bunch of users in my database and I want to reset all their usernames to the first letter of their first name, plus their full last name. As you can imagine, there are some dupes. In this scenario, I'd like to add a "2" or "3" or something to the end of the username. How would I write a query to generate a unique username like this?

```
UPDATE user
SET username=lower(concat(substring(first_name,1,1), last_name), UNIQUETHINGHERE)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE bar LIKE foo;

INSERT INTO bar (id,user,first,last)
(SELECT f.id,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(f.first,1,1),f.last,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo f2
         WHERE SUBSTRING(f2.first,1,1) = SUBSTRING(f.first,1,1)
               AND f2.last = f.last AND f2.id <= f.id
         )),f.first,f.last from foo f);

DROP TABLE foo;
RENAME TABLE bar TO foo;
```

This relies on a primary key `id`, so for each record inserted into `bar`, we only count duplicates found in `foo` with `id` less than `bar.id`.

Given foo:

```
select * from foo;
+----+------+--------+--------+
| id | user | first  | last   |
+----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | aaa  | Roger  | Hill   | 
|  2 | bbb  | Sally  | Road   | 
|  3 | ccc  | Fred   | Mount  | 
|  4 | ddd  | Darren | Meadow | 
|  5 | eee  | Sharon | Road   | 
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

The above `INSERT`s into `bar`, resulting in:

```
select * from bar;
+----+----------+--------+--------+
| id | user     | first  | last   |
+----+----------+--------+--------+
|  1 | RHill1   | Roger  | Hill   | 
|  2 | SRoad1   | Sally  | Road   | 
|  3 | FMount1  | Fred   | Mount  | 
|  4 | DMeadow1 | Darren | Meadow | 
|  5 | SRoad2   | Sharon | Road   | 
+----+----------+--------+--------+
```

---

To remove the "1" from the end of user names,

```
INSERT INTO bar (id,user,first,last)
(SELECT f3.id,
        CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING(f3.first,1,1),
            f3.last,
            CASE f3.cnt WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE f3.cnt END),
        f3.first,
        f3.last
 FROM (
    SELECT
        f.id,
        f.first,
        f.last,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM foo f2
            WHERE SUBSTRING(f2.first,1,1) = SUBSTRING(f.first,1,1)
            AND f2.last = f.last AND f2.id <= f.id
        ) as cnt
    FROM foo f) f3)
```

Comment: what's bar? why are there triple quotes at the end? care to explain this a bit?

Comment: @Mark: `bar` is an empty table like `foo`. After inserting records into `bar`, you can drop `foo` and rename `bar` --> `foo`. The triple quotes were an artifact of Python, where I tested the code.

Comment: Ah. I wanted to just update the user table, but I guess I can easily transfer it back. That's pretty cool. I'd also leave off the number if it's "1", but again, that should be easy to do. Nice! Thanks a lot! **Edit:** Like your comment explains.

Answer (score 5):

As a two-parter:

```
SELECT max(username)
FROM user
WHERE username LIKE concat(lower(concat(substring(first_name,1,1),lastname), '%')
```

to retrieve the "highest" username for that name combo. Extract the numeric suffix, increment it, then insert back into the database for your new user.

This is racy, of course. Two users with the same first/last names might stomp on each other's usernames, depending on how things work out. You'd definitely want to sprinkle some transaction/locking onto the queries to make sure you don't have any users conflicting.

Comment: I was hoping to do this with pure MySQL... this would require me to loop over all the users, no?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.... I just found the dupes:

```
select LOWER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(first_name,1,1),last_name)) as new_login,count(* ) as cnt from wx_user group by new_login having count(* )>1;
```

And set those ones manually. Was only a handful.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired in the answer of unutbu: there is no need to create an extra table neither several queries:

```
UPDATE USER a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT USR_ID, 
            REPLACE(
                CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING(f.`USR_FIRSTNAME`,1,1),
                    f.`USR_LASTNAME`,
                    (
                        (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 1, COUNT(*), '')
                            FROM USER f2
                            WHERE SUBSTRING(f2.`USR_FIRSTNAME`,1,1) = 
                                SUBSTRING(f.`USR_FIRSTNAME`,1,1)
                                AND f2.`USR_LASTNAME` = f.`USR_LASTNAME`
                                AND f2.`USR_ID` <= f.`USR_ID`)
                        )
                ),
                ' ',
                '') as login
        FROM USER f) b
    ON a.USR_ID = b.USR_ID
    SET a.USR_NICKNAME = b.login
```

Comment: I did my best to add enough indenting to this to make this readable, but this query is a bit of a monster the way it's written.

Comment: Why the downvote? It may be monstrous but it works and it can help people, I had the same problem and this is the solution I found, downvoting this gives the idea that this is wrong!

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but as originally answered, the lack of indentation made it unreadable.  I wager that's why.  [But asking "Why the downvote?" is generally considered bad style here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive)

Comment: I see, according with the link you provide just downvoting is also discouraged. I agree it was not readable but I just wanted to give people something to copy and paste and move on. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: Could you explain what this does/how it works? Looks like you're taking a character from here and there, but I can't really figure out what it's doing.

Comment: Oh..it's appending the count to the username? I don't think just adding the count is guaranteed to be unique. You might generate "mpen", discover "mpen" is taken, add a 2, but "mpen2" might also be taken. Also, your `count(*) > 1` bit looks suspicious, shouldn't it be  `count(*) >= 1` ? And will the first dupe start counting from 1 or 2?

Comment: @mpen It's not appending the count of all matching (first name char + last) combinations.  It's counting only those whose user ids are greater than or equal to the current one.  So the first user gets no number.  The second user gets a '2'.  And so on.

Comment: @user1930352: Not ideal behavior, no, but some people will immediately dismiss a post if they think it doesn't look like effort was put into it.  The ideal of SO is that every question and answer will be useful for answering other questions in the future.  Write-only code is strongly discouraged here. =)