# How do I get first name, middle name and last name as username with a dot in between the names and a number at the end for a unique username?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unique

I'm working on a project, but I would like to know how I get the first name, middle name and last name as the username with a dot in between their full names and a number at the end for a unique username? In MySQL. Just like Facebook's system. I also want so if the middle name is *NULL*, then it doesn't like a space in the middle.

I have tried a lot of different things, but nothing worked yet.

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(first_name, '.', COALESCE(CONCAT(middle_name, '.', last_name), 
first_name,middle_name,last_name)), middle_name,'.', COALESCE(CONCAT(first_name, '.', 
last_name),first_name,last_name)) AS username FROM users
```

That is how close I have come, but it has a problem if they don't have a middle name, it will display two dots instead of one. But I still need something to get the first name, middle name and last name as the username with a dot in between their full names and a number at the end for a unique username.

Comment: May be relevant: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want for the number at the end, but for the name, use `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws('.', first_name, middle_name, last_name)
```

If any of the values are `NULL` then the value is ignored (so `f.l` rather than `f..l`).

If you still want separators when the first/last name are `NULL`, then use `coalesce()`:

```
select concat_ws('.', coalesce(first_name, ''), middle_name, coalesce(last_name, ''))
```

You can concat a number at the end using `concat()` or by adding it as an argument (in which case, there will be a dot before the number).

Comment: What I meant by the number at the end, is if two or more users have the same first name and last name or even first name, middle name and last name, it would be nice to keep them spareted by a number at the end of their username, so they don't share same accounts, here I will link a screenshot to an example of the system that Facebook uses. 
http://i.imgur.com/NFAQ7bL.png

Comment: @AllanVester . . . It is entirely unclear from your question how you differentiate among users.  If you have a user id, you can use that (or some variation on it).

Comment: Okay, but I found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519892/generate-unique-username-from-first-and-last-name , this is exactly how I want it to be, but his code is a little unclear for me, because I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you want numbers at the end of the username then you can use the **id** or **SL** value of the user. The **ID** or **SL** column should be **NOT NULL**, **AUTO INCREMENT**. You can use:

```
select concat_ws('.', first_name, middle_name, last_name, id)
```